# OpenCV VideoCapture / V4L2 latency when grabbing a new webcam image

Tags: delay, webcam, video-capture, latency, v4l2

For a computer vision project that I am working on I need to grab images using a Logitech C920 webcam. I am using OpenCV's VideoCapture to do that, but the problem that I am facing is that the image that I take at a certain moment does not show the latest thing that the camera sees. That is, if I take an image at timestamp t, it shows what the camera saw at timestamp (t - delta), so to say.

I did this by writing a program that increments a counter and shows it on the screen. I pointed the camera at the screen and let it record. When the counter reached a certain value, say 10000, it would grab an image and save it with the filename "counter_value.png" (e.g. 10000.png). That way I was able to compare the current value of the counter with the current value seen by the camera. I noticed that most of the time the delay is about 4-5 frames, but it is not a fixed value.

I saw similar posts about this issue, but none of them really helped. Some people recommended putting the frame grabbing routine into a separate thread and updating a "current_frame" Mat variable. I tried that, but for some reason the issue is still present. Someone else mentioned that the camera worked well on Windows (but I need to use Linux, though). I tried running the same code on Windows and indeed the delay was only about 1 frame (which might as well be that the camera did not see the counter because the screen did not update fast enough).

I then decided to run a simple webcam viewer based only on V4L2 code, thinking that the issue might be coming from OpenCV. I again experienced the same delay, which makes me believe that the driver is using some sort of buffer to cache the images.

I am new to V4L2 and I really need to solve this problem as soon as possible, so my questions to you guys are:

1. Has anyone found a solution for getting the latest image using V4L2 (and maybe OpenCV)?
2. If there is no way to solve it using V4L2, does anyone know another alternative to fixing this issue on Linux?

Regards,

Mihai

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that there will be always a delay between the `VideoCapture::grab()` call and when the frame is actually taken. This is because of frame buffering that is done at hardware/SO level and you cannot avoid that.

OpenCV provides the `VideoCapture::get( CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MEC) )` method to give you the exact time a frame was captured, but this is only possible if the camera supports it.

Recently a problem has been discovered in V4L OpenCV implementation:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/61099/is-it-possible-to-get-frame-timestamps-for-live-streaming-video-frames-on-linux/

And a few days ago a fix has been pulled:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/3998

In the end, if you have the right setup, you can know what is the time a frame was taken (and therefore compensate).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the problem is with the Linux UVC driver, but I have been using Microsoft LifeCam Cinemas for machine vision on Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 machines, and have not seen a 4-5 frame delay.  I operate them in low light conditions, though, in which case they reduce the frame rate to 7.5 fps.

One other possible culprit is a delay *in the webcam* depending what format is used.  The C920 appears to support H.264 (which few webcams do), so Logitech may have put most effort to make this work well, yet OpenCV appears not to support H.264 on Linux; see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35161718/1628638) for what formats it supports.  The same question also has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23881125/1628638) with a kernel hack(!) to fix an issue with the UVC driver.

PS: to check the format actually used in my case, I added

```
fprintf(stderr, ">>> palette: %d\n", capture->palette);
```

at [this line](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.11/modules/highgui/src/cap_v4l.cpp#L597) in the OpenCV code.