# How do I enable the UVC_QUIRK_FIX_BANDWIDTH quirk in Linux UVC Driver?

Tags: linux, v4l2, uvc

I am currently trying to run 2 [webcams](http://www.geniusnet.com/Genius/wSite/ct?xItem=53211&ctNode=161) on a Wandboard board, which have to share a USB hub. Problem is , the current driver implementation (YUV only) saturates the USB hub and in the end I can only connect one camera.

However the UVC driver implementation has a quirk for this [kind](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/faq/#faq6) of situation, and others.

Problem is, I did not find any documentation on how to load these quirks.
Could you please assist me with that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can change the behaviour of many kernel-modules by passing some parameters.

you can get a list of all available module parameters with the `modinfo` command:

```
# modinfo uvcvideo
```

shows that there is a "quirks" parameters, which can be used.
looking at the [faq](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/faq/#faq6) you posted, it seems that the `quirks` are really a bitfield, so if you want to enable multiple quirks, you have to add the numbers.

first unload the driver (obviously you must not use it when doing so):

```
 # rmmod uvcvideo
```

then re-load it with the `quirks` parameter.
assuming you want to enable  both `UVC_QUIRK_FIX_BANDWIDTH` (which has the hex-value `0x80`, which is `128` in decimal) and `UVC_QUIRK_RESTRICT_FRAME_RATE` (which is `0x200` thus `512`) you would use a quirks value of `640` (which is `128+512` resp. `0x200|0x80`):

```
 # modprobe uvcvideo quirks=640
```

Comment: To get the current value: `cat /sys/module/uvcvideo/parameters/quirks`

Answer (score 8):

To make umläute's answer survive reboots, I created file `/etc/modprobe.d/uvcvideo.conf` with content

```
options uvcvideo quirks=0x80
```

To get the module to reload `uvcvideo.conf`, unload and load the module:

```
rmmod uvcvideo
modprobe uvcvideo
```

Interestingly, using `echo` to set `quirks` (i.e., while `uvcvideo` is loaded) did not work, even though the [UVC driver FAQ](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/faq/) uses `echo` to modify the `trace` parameter of `uvcvideo`.

Note: UVC_QUIRK_FIX_BANDWIDTH enabled many Microsoft LifeCam Cinema webcams per USB host controller in my case (on Ubuntu 14.04) for a machine vision application.  The LifeCam Cinema reserves about 48% of USB 2.0 bandwidth (according to Device Manager on Windows), so without the quirk one can operate at most two LifeCams per host controller.  (For several host controller chips, I was even limited to one LifeCam without the quirk.)

Comment: PS: the quirk is not operational for compressed formats (but the LifeCam, e.g., still reserves 48% of USB 2.0 bandwidth); this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23881125/1628638) has a UVC driver hack to make the quirk also work for compressed formats.  Have not tried the hack but code looked correct.  :)

Comment: For my Quelima at was `quirks=2` as option. Work like a charm :)